# Does true wireless 3-way switch exist?

Tags: switch, multiway-switch

I currently have a 3-way switch setup which is made up of two 3-way switches to control a hallway light. Due to oversight, an additional (4-way) light switch is much desired in the middle of the hallway.

The cost of opening up the wall and rewiring the 3-way circuit to accommodate a new 4-way switch is prohibitive.

The wiring is new and all the switches have neutral. I am wondering if there exists a wireless switch (looks like a wall switch but without wires behind) that can be used to toggle another 3-way switch over wireless such that I can have a 4-way setup.

I have looked at several products. Many of the so called "wireless 3-way switch set" is really a wireless controlled single pole switch that turns existing single switch into 3-way.

Here is an example of such "fake" 3-way:
[https://www.amazon.com/SK-8-Wireless-Anywhere-Lighting-Control/dp/B0052ROEB2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052ROEB2)

Does it exists a set similar to above but replaces a 3-way switch?

Comment: I am looking for the same thing.  A true SPDT (single pole double throw) switch that is wireless.  With wireless switch products like Leviton's, to simply add a single wireless location to a normal 3 and 4-way circuit requires you to replace ALL of the circuit's switches entirely and depend on their technology for all 3 and 4-way locations.  Why can't somebody make a wireless SPDT using the same framework as their wireless SPST switches?

Comment: I'm sure you have figured it out by now, but this product looks like it would fulfill your needs. https://www.amazon.com/Suraielec-Wireless-Switch-Receiver-Bundle/dp/B0CT2DP9S7. I am looking for a similar solution and I think I will do this. 1 master, 2 remotes. One remote will go into an existing 3-way hole, the other will go on the wall in the middle. The product says you can connect multiple remotes to one master

Comment: Yes, I believe I have the answer. But the one you linked does not look like what I want. The IoT space has changed a bit. I will make answer with the correct product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True 3-Way Smart Switches (Or as user @Sparky calls it, True Wireless SPDT Smart Switch) are now available.

Here are a couple of examples:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B095X8YD3Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B095X8YD3Q)

[https://www.amazon.com/Z-Wave-Solution-Regular-Switches-Required/dp/B0921F1KVY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0921F1KVY)

Both explicitly mentioned that they can be used to directly replace one of the 3-way switches. Specifically, the one connected to LOAD (such that it is always powered). I am glad that companies step up to fill the gap in the market. There is really no need for a "companion" smart switch.

Answer (score 3):

You had the right product in the first place.

The product you linked as your "I wish this did that" **does that**.

If you scroll down, you can see the "frequently bought with" and suggested products includes a unit that is *just* a remote.   You buy another one and pair it to the receiver, which goes in one of the 3-way swirch locations.  Thea other 3-way is abandoned electrically and replaced with one of the remotes.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Honestly, I have not thought of that! However, both my 3-way switches are in a multi-gang setting and a switch that controls nothing is just silly. Also, I will have to find another location for an extra remote. I would say it is still a no-go for me.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if you are decommissioning one of the 3-ways, would that not provide you with a location for the switch?  I suppose you could hunt for a product which is similar to the above, but also makes a remote designed to be wired and installed like a normal switch (while making a wireless remote *too*.)   The smart-device revolution gives endless possibilities.  You might consider asking at a lighting or electrical supply house, which is a type of specialty seller (not a big-box).

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question. I want to turn a 3-way setup into 4-way. My expectation is adding an additional remote switch. Ideally, the only wiring I need to do is replace a standard 3-way switch with a receiver 3-way switch (which still works as a switch). I have searched high and low to no avail. I have done my homework and I don't really see anything wrong for asking advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can get pretty close.

"...looks like a wall switch but without wires behind..." Assuming here that your looking for the standard *TOGGLE* light switch, then you're not likely going to find the exact product.

If Decora or paddle style wall switch is acceptable, then replace *both* existing 3 way ends with [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008HUWWOC) or [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZTVZ0W) (the difference is the first is on/off only, the second also Dims- choose the dimmer if the hall light is dimming compatible).

For the middle location choose [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005LIH41O) wireless switch plus a [mounting bracket](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005LIH496) and any [standard Decora or paddle switch wall plate](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HEHCE6).

Initial set-up (specifically *linking*) is slightly confusing if you've never before used Insteon products, wiring is however straight-forward.  Insteon (also known as smarthome.com) does have good phone support (although their phone system produces horrible call quality-if that happens ask the support person to call you back as calls in that direction don't seem to be affected).

You also need a [standard USB cable](http://www.smarthome.com/mini-remote-usb-charging-cable-type-a-to-micro-b-6-foot.html) and perhaps an [adapter](http://www.smarthome.com/mini-remote-usb-power-adapter.html) to charge the wireless switch. (the middle switch will only need charging a few times a year). Honestly you likely already have this standard USB cable, it's pretty standard and the same used to connect most camera's and non-apple phones to a computer or charger.   (I put smarthome.com links for the last two because those two items appear to cost much more when purchased via amazon.)

Disclaimer: I do NOT work for Insteon/Smarthome.com. I do work for a company that has a sales/installation agreement with Instean/Smarthome.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: I couldn't find anything like that either.

Instead, I would suggest replacing your existing three-ways with a vacancy type switch such as [this](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_14?url=search-alias%3Dtools&field-keywords=lutron+motion+sensor+light+switch&sprefix=Lutron+motion+%2Ctools%2C178&crid=1S0WVQZBGKYKG). And its companion switch [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006V5PXK).

These can be programmed to come on automatically or manually. And then they shut off automatically after a programmed amount of time.

Good luck in your search.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do the same same thing and based on my research the SK-8 Wireless DIY 3-Way you mentioned ( [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0052ROEB2/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0052ROEB2) )may be the best option. I ordered it but looking at the product page description i'm not in live with it either. But it should do what i'm trying to do for now which is to have a way to turn on my kitchen light at both entrances.

It's such a simple solution i would have thought there would be many more options with all these different smart switch models on the market these day.

oh well...

Comment: I eventually bought the SK-8 but not for replacing my 3-way switch but for another remote need. It works fine except the relative short battery live (have to replace battery after 1-2 years). Since my post, there has been some Smart Switch like https://www.amazon.com/Z-Wave-Switch-ZEN21-Existing-Regular/dp/B074CJ1ZRF which claims to work with existing 3-way switch. However, I must have a hub because it is a "Smart" switch. Also, a good wireless "Smart" switch is surprisingly difficult to find.